# query wouldn't use suitable index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query

```
db.Product.find({
    CategoryPath: /^399-305-352(-\d+)*$/,
    "Availability.Status": {
        $lt: 4
    },
    $or: [{
        _id: {
            $lt: 331000000
        }
    }, {
        _id: {
            $gt: 852000000,
            $lt: 853000000
        }
    }, {
        _id: {
            $gt: 972000000,
            $lt: 973000000
        }
    }]
}).sort({
    "Availability.Status": 1,
    Popularity: -1
});
```

with explain I find it uses index `Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1`:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 913,
    "nscannedObjects" : 470239,
    "nscanned" : 470239,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1387264,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1387264,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 10838,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 10117,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "Availability.Status" : [
            [
                -Infinity,
                4
            ]
        ],
        "Popularity" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "dal05mgo13.sl.dx:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

this is pretty slow for me. I actually have another index  `CategoryPath_1_Availability.Status_1` which I think is a better choice. but when I force mongodb to use it with `hint`, I get an error:

```
{
  "$err" : "Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33581891 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes",
  "code" : 17144
}
```

Now what I don't understand is, with the conditions specified in `find`, there are only `913` results selected, even without index, `sort` shouldn't have used up 32MB memory to sort the 913 records. Can anyone tell me what's happening?

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.10 x86_64

**EDIT**: my colleague just created a new index `Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1_CategoryPath_1` which is now winning from other plans. I still don't understand why though. Here are the detail explain info:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1_CategoryPath_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 913,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1325,
    "nscanned" : 1930,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 7729,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 8334,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 64,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 45,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "Availability.Status" : [
            [
                -Infinity,
                4
            ]
        ],
        "Popularity" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "CategoryPath" : [
            [
                "399-305-352",
                "399-305-353"
            ],
            [
                /^399-305-352(-\d+)*$/,
                /^399-305-352(-\d+)*$/
            ]
        ]
    },
    "allPlans" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1_CategoryPath_1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "n" : 913,
            "nscannedObjects" : 1325,
            "nscanned" : 1930,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "Availability.Status" : [
                    [
                        -Infinity,
                        4
                    ]
                ],
                "Popularity" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "CategoryPath" : [
                    [
                        "399-305-352",
                        "399-305-353"
                    ],
                    [
                        /^399-305-352(-\d+)*$/,
                        /^399-305-352(-\d+)*$/
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 306,
            "nscanned" : 306,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "Availability.Status" : [
                    [
                        -Infinity,
                        4
                    ]
                ],
                "Popularity" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "clauses" : [
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 305,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 305,
                    "nscanned" : 305,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                852000000,
                                853000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                972000000,
                                973000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                -Infinity,
                                331000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 305,
            "nscanned" : 305,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0
        },
        {
            "clauses" : [
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 7,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 7,
                    "nscanned" : 7,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                972000000,
                                973000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_1_Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 297,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 297,
                    "nscanned" : 297,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                852000000,
                                853000000
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Availability.Status" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Popularity" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                -Infinity,
                                331000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 304,
            "nscanned" : 304,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0
        },
        {
            "clauses" : [
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 305,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 305,
                    "nscanned" : 305,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                852000000,
                                853000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_1_Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                972000000,
                                973000000
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Availability.Status" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Popularity" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                -Infinity,
                                331000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 305,
            "nscanned" : 305,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0
        },
        {
            "clauses" : [
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_1_Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 305,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 305,
                    "nscanned" : 305,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                852000000,
                                853000000
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Availability.Status" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Popularity" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_1_Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                972000000,
                                973000000
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Availability.Status" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Popularity" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                -Infinity,
                                331000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 305,
            "nscanned" : 305,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0
        },
        {
            "clauses" : [
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 305,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 305,
                    "nscanned" : 305,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                852000000,
                                853000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                972000000,
                                973000000
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_1_Availability.Status_1_Popularity_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                -Infinity,
                                331000000
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Availability.Status" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Popularity" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 305,
            "nscanned" : 305,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0
        }
    ],
    "server" : "dal05mgo12.sl.dx:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "FETCH",
        "works" : 1931,
        "yields" : 64,
        "unyields" : 64,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 913,
        "needTime" : 1017,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "forcedFetches" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 913,
        "children" : [
            {
                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                "works" : 1931,
                "yields" : 64,
                "unyields" : 64,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 1325,
                "needTime" : 605,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : "{ Availability.Status: 1.0, Popularity: -1.0, CategoryPath: 1.0 }",
                "isMultiKey" : 1,
                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['Availability.Status']: [-inf.0, 4.0), field #1['Popularity']: [MaxKey, MinKey], field #2['CategoryPath']: [\"399-305-352\", \"399-305-353\"), [/^399-305-352(-\\d+)*$/, /^399-305-352(-\\d+)*$/]",
                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 1325,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 1930,
                "children" : [ ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us `.hint("your index def").explain(1)` so we can see the full rejected plans.

Comment: @BlakesSeven There are too many indexes there, I'll have to remove some meaningless ones before post here. Just a moment.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Actually what I don't understand is, does mongodb sort the documents before filtering? That's the only possibility why the `Overflow` happens.

Comment: Please don't remove unless you are completely sure, and since you are the one asking the question then not removing is well advised. But "too many indicies" is already scaring me and it sounds like there is a lot of indicies defined that should probably not be there.

Comment: And that is why at least "I" want to see the full explain "verbose" output, since it does not seem like the index is being selected for processing at all, or there is at least a strong reason why it is being rejected.

Comment: @BlakesSeven We previously uses 2.4 which uses only one index to fulfill query. So there are a lot of compound indexes.

Comment: Just to let you know. I'm already submitting this to moderators to "clean up the chat". My comment at the very top calls to you to "please edit your question with more information". So it might be well to consider here that "less chat" and more "presenting requested information" is the way to proceed here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I removed some plans which I think is not so much useful. and the plans are there.

Comment: You still haven't done what I asked. Where is the `.explain(1)` output when you provide the `.hint()` ?

Comment: @Blakes Seven Because there's now the new index winning the other plans. Should I hint with old index and post that output?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the order of the fields in the index matters.

CategoryPath_1_Availability.Status_1 translates for the following indexing order: index by CategoryPath then by Availability.Status.

But you want the index to start with Availability.Status, and mongo checks to see if there is any index that starts with Availability.Status (ascending), and there isn't (before your friend created the new index). Order matters :)

As a general rule: lets say you have the following **fields** in a collection: **a, b and c**. Let's set an **index on a and b** (a ascending, b ascending). **You will be able to use this index in a sort only if the sort starts with a** (ascending), **or a** (ascending) **and b** (ascending). Hope you understand :)

Comment: Here's a question, as you can see there are only 900+ documents selected. Why wouldn't mongodb use my index and sort without index? It would have taken less resource this way. And when I hint with my index, here comes memory overflow. The only explanation is that mongodb is doing sorting before filtering. That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: that's because you're asking mongo to use a bad index for that query.

Comment: Yes I know. what I mean is, mongo could have used the index I provided, and sort without index. I think sort 900 records in memory is not a big deal. Somehow, mongo decided to sort all the 500,000 records before filtering. that's the part I don't understand.

Comment: actually, mongo applies the sort first, then the filter, that's how it works